# Simulate app with Firebase services in China

Tags: firebase, service, firewall, simulate, great-firewall-of-china

My app uses FireBase services such as notifications, crash reports and more.
I know that some Google services are blocked in China, is there a way for me to simulate (from outside China) how my app will perform in China in order to test what services are blocked and what will be the effect to the app?

Answer (score 2):

All google.com urls are blocked in China. Since all references to Firebase are using google.com, it is pretty much guaranteed that no parts of your app will be able to access any Firebase services when used from inside China. You may use simulators like [Dotcom Tools](https://www.dotcom-tools.com/website-speed-test.aspx?se=14030f0be58a42b4b83609b7edd1520a&_ga=2.159927869.1643063713.1512664248-844954036.1512664248) to understand accessibility of Urls from China.

Additionally, you can read here on how to get a China VPN address and then simulate accessing the Firebase services from there: [VPN into China].[2](https://www.vpndada.com/vpn-into-china/)

But also do note that Google Playstore is not accessible from China. So users in China cannot download Android app either (unless yours is iOS).

So you will have to find alternative mechanism to distribute and run your app for the Chinese market.